# Permissions on apache2 directory

Tags: apache, webserver

I was working through [these](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13/) instructions to get my web server working again and needed to change the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file.

I needed to change the permission on `httpd.conf` file and did. Next I attempted to edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. I could not because I didn't have permission to change things in the `/etc/apache2` directory. So I tried a `chmod 666` on the `/etc/apache2` directory.  Now I cannot see any contents in finder in the `/etc/apache2/` directory. The permissions I can see on the directory are: `drw-rw-rw-`. In Finder it shows as a custom permissions.

I need to change the permissions on `/etc/apache2` but to what?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/333538/edit) your question to clearly state your query. This will help in getting quick and relevant answers.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when running `chmod 666` on `/etc/apache2`. What does the output of `ls -ld /etc/apache2` says?

Comment: drw-rw-rw-  11 root  wheel  352 Apr 30 18:33 /etc/apache2

Comment: yes I did use sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't have permission to change things in the `apache2` directory.

Because the directory is owned by root user and not the logged-in user.

> Now I cannot see any contents in finder in the `apache2` directory.

Because the current permission is on `apache2` directory is `drw-rw-rw-`, hence you cannot change (`cd`) into that directory, as you are missing the **execute** (`x`) permission bit. Add the execute permission to be able to change to `apache2` directory. Execute the following command-line:

`sudo chmod a+x /etc/apache2`

To edit the `httpd.conf` (or any other file), use `sudo`, like:

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Comment: Perfect.  No points because I am newbie but it is exactly what is needed.

Comment: Great. Did it work for you?

Comment: It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Pam Good to hear. Kindly accept the answer so that others having similar problem will know it’s helpful.

Comment: Really am a newbie... I have tried clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange platform :) To lean about how the Q&A site works, you can get started by taking the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). For a thorough introduction you can check out the [help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help) section. Good luck :)